# Error 404 While Hosting the website in the GCP bucket using Load Banacer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am trying to host the Simple website in the GCP with Loadbalancer(for HTTPS) with the custom domain

Below are the Steps that I followed

- Create the Bucket
- Make it public
- Set the website configuration for the bucket

### For load balancer

- Create the new backend with the bucket
- Create the Static IP
- Create the Google managed SSL certificate to my domain `cloud.joshuajebaraj.com`

### In the DNS provider

- I mapped the IP to the domain

But When I hit the domain its showing a 404

I attached the Screenshot to my load  balancer configuration and the DNS setting
[Loadbalancer Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FHSL.png)
[DNS setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOZ8o.png)

Comment: 1) You have not configured an HTTP Front End. 2) Your SSL certificate appears to have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that billing is enabled for your Cloud project.
2. Have the following Identity and Access Management roles: Storage Object Admin
   and Network Admin.
3. You need to add your bucket to a load balancer's
   backend and add a new Google-managed SSL certificate to the load balancer's
   front end.
4. **Configure the front end**.You can refer this link [1] for reference. (I don't see you mentioning configuring front-end
   for your bucket)
5. After the load balancer is created, click the name of your load balancer,note the IP address associated with the load balancer: for example, 30.90.80.100. To point your domain to your load balancer, create an A record using your domain registration service. If you added multiple domains to your SSL certificate, you must add an A record for each one, all pointing to the load balancer's IP address.
6. Provision the certificate and make the site available through the load balancer. To monitor the status of your certificate:

Load balancing page in the Google Cloud Console --->Click on name of your load balancer --->Click on the name of the SSL certificate associated with the load balancer --->The Status and Domain status rows show the certificate status. **Both must be active in order for the certificate to be valid for your website**

[1]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website